# tk: widgets need to be defined in order?

Tags: widget, tk-toolkit

I am trying to build a GUI with tk. Very new to this tool, find an issue, which is not mentioned in manual. 
the following code works well: 
`frame .frm`
`label .lab -text "input:"`
`entry .ent`

`grid .lab -in .frm  -row 1 -column 1`
`grid .ent -in .frm  -row 1 -column 2`
`pack .frm`

but when i change the order of defining the widgets like following:
`label .lab -text "input:"`
`entry .ent`
`frame .frm`

`grid .lab -in .frm  -row 1 -column 1`
`grid .ent -in .frm  -row 1 -column 2`
`pack .frm`

the come out window shows nothing inside. So it seems that the parent widget needs to be defined first ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the information you need: http://wiki.tcl.tk/12752.  See the section titled "Stacking Order - Rules".

As Mr. Oakley points out, you could also add to your second script:

```
raise .lab .frm
raise .ent .frm
```

But it's generally easier to define your stacking order by creating the widgets in that order in the first place.

I don't know why it's not documented.  Documentation on packing order (important when resizing) is lacking also.

Comment: Your answer would be better f it actually answered the question rather than just link to an external resource. See [are answers that just contain links elsewhere really good answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: The answer is 'yes', and the original poster has already figured that out.  I see no need in this case to duplicate what is elsewhere.  No explanation I make will be better than the specified link.  Of course link rot will set in eventually...

Comment: Actually, the answer isn't strictly yes. You can define them in any order, because you can change the stacking order after the widgets are created. Imagine the frustration of someone learning by visiting a Q&A site, and every answer takes you to a different site.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with the assertion.  But can you also imagine when there are dozens of answers to the same question, all different, and no reference to a reliable source (that's pretty much what the web's like now, and without timestamps also).

Comment: That's why we all should strive to write a nice summary _and_ link to authorative documentation.